# Adding an item to a Collection within a Collection

Tags: c#-4.0

This is my object structure,

```
Group has         
     List of Offers
Offer has 
     GroupId
     List of Products
```

How can I add a product to the already existing List of products based on Group ID

This code is adding the Product but overwriting the existing product

```
Group.OffersList.Where(x => x.GroupId == "1")
                .SelectMany(x => x.ProductList)
                .ToList().Add(Product);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Group.OffersList.Where(x => x.GroupId == "1")
                 .ToList()
                 .ForEach(x => x.Add(Product));
```